# What api to use in crossrider extension to schedule code to run periodically

Tags: google-chrome-extension, crossrider

I have developed Google chrome extension in which I am using chrome.alarms api. (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms) I am moving this extension to crossrider now. Is there any equivalent api in crossrider for chrome.alarms api.

How can I schedule code to run periodically in crossrider extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `chrome.alarms` API exists because of [event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages), which are inactive background pages (to save memory and resources).

In Crossrider, the background page is persistent, i.e. it never suspends unless the browser is closed. There is no direct `chrome.alarms` equivalent in Crossrider, but you rewrite your code to schedule tasks with timers using [`appAPI.setInterval`](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI-method-setInterval) (periodic) and [`appAPI.setTimeout`](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI-method-setTimeout) (once) as primitives.